# Which iOS browser forces desktop mode universally which supports file uploads?

Tags: ios, safari, google-chrome, firefox, web-browsing

I would like to use the desktop version of a particular site on an iPhone (iOS 15.6).

I can confirm that many browsers do not universally force desktop view, but only do it on certain sites. That includes Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and Edge.

So far, the only browser I have found that can do this is Opera.

However, I can confirm by testing on two websites that Opera cannot upload files to an HTML "upload file" button. It launches the iOS view to select a file, and after you select one, the webpage does not receive it, and the field appears blank.

I can still try the other iOS browsers that I know of:

Tor, Brave, Insight, Aloha, and surprisingly many more available in the App Store.

Does anyone know of any iOS browser that can force desktop view universally and also supports file uploads, or generally, complete desktop-like functionality?

Comment: By the way, I am also looking into the following workarounds: the Insight browser appears to have a rich extension ecosystem, so maybe I could make this extension for Insight. Otherwise, I probably have to automate site interaction in Selenium, or maybe use a remote connection app to display a web browser running in kiosk mode on a cloud server, which I could consider. Interested in any other tips. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. If it's relevant, please add that comment to your question.

Comment: I used to use the iCab browser many years ago for file uploading or downloading, it's been a while but I do recall it has an astonishing level of customization